# Can't resolve hostname in local network - whats wrong with my resolver configuration?

Tags: networking, dns, systemd

I'm using kubuntu 18.04 (*upgraded from various previous versions (non-LTS)*) and have problems to resolv hostnames in my local network. No DNS query is sent to the resolver for local names (*confirmed by wireshark*).
If I direcly ask the resolver, the name is resolved:

```
ian@martok:~$ host cubietruck
Host cubietruck not found: 2(SERVFAIL)

ian@martok:~$ host cubietruck 192.168.0.5
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.0.5
Address: 192.168.0.5#53
Aliases: 

cubietruck has address 192.168.0.220
```

The systemd resolver configuration looks fine:

```
ian@martok:~$ systemd-resolve --status           
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      [...]
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                                                                                                                                                                    
       LLMNR setting: yes                                                                                                                                                                    
MulticastDNS setting: no                                                                                                                                                                     
      DNSSEC setting: no                                                                                                                                                                     
    DNSSEC supported: no                                                                                                                                                                     
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.5
```

I also changed `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, but that does no change the behaviour (even after reboot) (old line commented out):

```
#hosts:          files mdns4_minimal resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns mdns4
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal resolve dns [!UNAVAIL=return] mdns4
```

Other device in my network can resolv local hostnames correctly.

Comment: `host` does not use NSS. It directly queries DNS servers specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Please show your `/etc/resolv.conf` contents.

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf:
`nameserver 127.0.0.53`

However, the problem is not only the `host` command - I can't resolve `cubietruck`  at all, e.g `ping cubietruck` doesn't work, too.

Comment: does it work with `systemd-resolve cubietruck`?

Comment: Nope:

`ian@martok:~$ systemd-resolve cubietruck`
:

`cubietruck: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found`

Comment: The working /etc/nsswitch.conf has a hosts: line like:  hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname  This is from a fresh install of 18.04 with the libnss-resolve package added. Works for local names, and big DNS outputs.